# Division by 0 in TurboPascal7

Tags: pascal, freepascal, digits, turbo-pascal

I am working on my school project and I am (almost) furious about this issue. My solution's validity is 95 %, but I have 1 input wrong – I don't know the input, but I know, that the input failed because of the error code 200, which is divison by 0.

My project is this:

> **„The digit sum of an integer is defined to be the sum of the digits in the integer's written form. Usually we calculate the digit sum using a number's decimal (base 10) representation, but in this exercise we will compute it in a given base. Write a function that computes a natural number's digit sum when the number is written in a given base. Using this function, write a program that reads two natural numbers (each on its own line, and both in decimal representation): a base B and a number N. The output should be N's digit sum in base B (written in decimal representation).“**

I have tried to fix the problem by adding 2 conditions, but it did nothing, mistake still exists.
I am using a formula, which can be found here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digit_sum . 
Here is the code itself, it is not long.

```
program CifernySoucetZobecneny;

var
  Soustava, Cislo, i: longint;
  HorniMez: longint;
  Soucet: real;

function Mocnina(Zaklad: longint; Exponent: longint): longint;
var
  i, Pomoc: longint;
begin
  Pomoc := 1;

  for i := 1 to Exponent do
  begin
    Pomoc := Pomoc * Zaklad;
  end;

  Mocnina := Pomoc;
end;

begin
  readLn(Soustava);
  readLn(Cislo);

  if (Soustava = 0) then
  begin
    writeLn('0');
    exit;
  end;

  if (Soustava = 1) then
  begin
    writeLn(Cislo);
    exit;
  end;

  HorniMez := Trunc(Ln(Cislo)/Ln(Soustava));
  Soucet := 0;

  for i := 0 to HorniMez do
  begin
    Soucet := Soucet + ((1/Mocnina(Soustava, (i)))*((Cislo mod Mocnina(Soustava, (i+1))) - (Cislo mod Mocnina(Soustava, i))));
  end;

  writeLn(Soucet:0:0);
end.
```

I would be grateful if someone could look at the code and told me, where am I dividing by 0, because I tried many inputs, spend many hours on this and did not come with the correct solution. Thank you all.

PS: I am Czech, so the names of the variables and functions are not in English, sorry for that, but I hope, that it will not be a problem.

Comment: *I don't know the input, but I know, that the input failed*. You're saying you don't know what user input to your program causes it to fail?

Comment: You've taken care of the `Ln(Soustava)` case by not allowing `Soustava` to be 1 (although, your program allows negative numbers to be entered, which fail). Your `mod` is suspect in this case. If the second argument to `mod` is 0, you have a divide-by-zero scenario. In other words, if `Mocnina(Sousstava, i+1)` returns 0, you're in trouble. Since `Mocnina` just does integer exponentiation, then perhaps it's an integer overflow condition where the overflow happens to be 0.

Comment: Do some debugging. Why do people not debug anymore?

Comment: lurker – No I do not, it is a testing program, which validates my program, simply it has some (for me) secret inputs and test if my output is correct or not.
And yes, I have taken care of Ln(Soustava), where, to be dividing by logarithm be defined, Soustava (argument) cannot be ONE. Also I have taken care of by the other condition the problem, when Soustava = 0, so I could divide (or use "mod") by Mocnina(Soustava, i) and Mocnina(Soustava, (i+1)). Also the 2 given numbers on the start of the program are natural, so they surely cannot be negative. That's why I decided to ask for help here.

Comment: David Heffernan – I said, that I tested my program with many inputs, but how can I debug if the results for my inputs are correct?

Comment: You have an error. Debug your program. Do you know how to debug?

Comment: David Heggernan – I think I know how to debug program in TurboPascal7, but as I asked you, why would I debug (used watches, traced into etc.) if all my inputs gave me correct outputs? In another words, I dont know on which kind of inputs will my program fail. OR maybe I just dont understand your point or you dont understand my point.

Comment: If all the inputs give correct answers, what is the problem?

Comment: David Heffernan – all the inputs I could think of, not all the inputs there are in the world. To be exact, testing program from school, which validates my program, gave me 19 out of 20 correct inputs, so there is 1 kind of inputs, on which will my program fail. I hoped, when I asked here about my problem, that someone could figure out on which inputs will my program fail, because I wasn't able to figure it out myself, I have run out of ideas. Only thing I know is, that the program will fail in 1 out of 20 inputs because he is trying to divide by 0.

Comment: So find the input that fails, and debug that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `Cislo = 0`, a following calculation of `Ln(Cislo)` gives the runtime error 200. That is because `Ln(0)` is undefined (outside the allowed range of `Ln()`).

Comment: Thank you kindly sir. I am studying theoretical mathematics and we havent defined that the number ZERO is in the set of natural numbers . You have the correct idea. Thank you for your help and have a nice day.

Comment: This has nothing at all to do with natural numbers, @Palindrom

Comment: @DavidHeffernan – you are incorrect. Function logarithm is defined on interval (0, infty). If I assumed, that the set of natural numbers is not {0, 1, ...}, BUT {1, 2, 3, ...}, and in the task the input data should be only natural numbers, I thought (wrongly), that I do not have to test the case, when Cislo = 0.

Comment: The definition of natural numbers may vary, but at least in the ISO definition, zero is included.

Comment: The domain of log are the strictly positive real numbers. Natural numbers are whole numbers. When it comes to maths I like to think I know what I am talking about.